# DataWeave Mule : Extract from String data after particular character

Tags: dataweave, mule-esb

I have a requirement to extract data from a string after the occurence of '@'. Example abc@123456 should result in 123456. I am doing htis in DataWeave Mule.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `splitBy` for this, then grab what you need by index:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

%var data = ("abc@123456" splitBy "@")[1]
---
data
```

This will set the payload to String: `"123456"`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the regular expression `/.*@(.*)/` to find the last occurrence of `@` and return the group that follows, regardless of how many `@` symbols occur in the input string.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var regex = /.*@(.*)/

%var data1 = ("abc@123456" match regex)[1]
%var data2 = ("xyz@abc@123456" match regex)[1]
%var data3 = ("xy@@z@abc@123456" match regex)[1]
%var data4 = ("name@example.com" match regex)[1]
---

result: { 
    data1: data1,
    data2: data2,
    data3: data3,
    data4: data4 
}
```

This gives the following results:

```
{
  "data1": "123456",
  "data2": "123456",
  "data3": "123456",
  "data4": "example.com"
}
```